# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"textarea[name='to']"}

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, ui-automation

I am writing an email from compose page on gmail service. The issue is that Web Driver can't find 'To' input on compose page

Here is my code:
EmailPage

```
private readonly IWebDriver driver;

public EmailPage(IWebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
}

public IWebElement ComposeButton => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".T-I.T-I-KE.L3"));
public IWebElement ToField => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("textarea[name='to']"));
public IWebElement SubjectField => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='subjectbox']"));
public IWebElement BodyField => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".Am.Al.editable.LW-avf"));
public IWebElement SendButton => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".T-I.J-J5-Ji.aoO.v7.T-I-atl.L3"));

public void ComposeEmail(string to, string subject, string body)
{
    ComposeButton.Click();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    ToField.SendKeys(to);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    SubjectField.SendKeys(subject);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    BodyField.SendKeys(body);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    SendButton.Click();
}
```

EmailTestPage

```
[Test]
public void TestLogin()
{
    EmailPage emailPage = homePage.GoToEmail();

    string toInput = "example@gmail.com";
    string subject = "For Test";
    string body = "This is just a test";

    emailPage.ComposeEmail(toInput, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: Have been trying everything for 1 week and still got nothing (

Comment: From what I see on gmail page, element with name = 'to' is a 'div', so your css selector for ToField should be: "div[name='to'] input".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a CSS selector here. It looks like the 'To' field has an ID, so you could try:

```
public IWebElement ToField => driver.FindElement(By.Id(":1id"));
```

This is what the Id looks like on my Gmail, but it could be different for you.

Ultimately, a test should avoid going to Gmail in the first place. Try using the Gmail API to send the message instead.

Disclaimer: I have not personally used the Gmail api, but this article seems to make the most sense for .net applications.
https://mycodebit.com/send-emails-in-asp-net-core-5-using-gmail-api/